# Visual Studio 2015: unreadable chars in the `Output` window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

MS Visual Studio 2015 English Enterprise Update 1.

I see unreadable chars in the `Output` window when I build my project:

[image]

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Having text encoding problems with I/O redirection is common, seems it wants to tell you something in a double-byte encoding.  Usually East-Asian.   Since you don't appear to realize that the project's post-build event is relevant, or you would have posted it, start looking there.

Answer (score 0):

Try This : Changing the font of the output window can also address the issue of the characters.

In VS go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors ->Show Settings for: Output Window

Comment: It has `Consolas` font now in my IDE. What font is better for using at this case? The `Courier New` and `Lucida Console` fonts didn't solve my problem also.